# Ergodic Channal Capacity in MIMO Systems

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to verify the proposition that the ergodic sum channel capacity in wireless MIMO increases linearly with the number of K users at the receiver (i.e receive antenna) as stated [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1391204/) based on the equation

C = E[log2(det(I_M + roh*H'*D*H))]

where

- D = (1/K)I_K, (I_K is an identity matrix of dimension KxK)
- roh = 10dB
- I_M is an identity matrix

This is my MATLAB code, but wasn't getting the required plot.

```
clear; close all; clc;
n_iter = 1000;             %% NUMBER OF ITERATIONS
roh = 10^(10/10);          %% TRANSMITER POWER
K = 1:20;                  % NUMBER OF USERS
M = 20;                    % NUMBER OF ANTENNNA
for ii = 1: n_iter
    for kk = 2 : length(K)
        I_M = eye(min(kk,M));
        H = 1/sqrt(2) * (randn(kk, M) + 1i * randn(kk, M)); %% RANDOM CHANNEL
        if  kk >= M
            HH = H' * H;
        else
            HH = H * H';
        end
    end
    C(:,kk) = zeros(1, kk);
    for jj = 2 : length(K)  
        C(:, jj) = C(:, jj) + log2(real(det((I_M + roh * HH/jj)))); %% CHANNEL CAPACITY
    end
end
C_avr = sum(C, 1)/n_iter;
plot(1:length(K), C_avr)
```

Comment: Nice question. But checkout the [ask] and [mcve] to see details about how to ask a good question. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve (plot something? verify something?) and what isn't working.

Comment: My main goal is to generate the plot in order to confirm the proposition as stated in the paper given in the link.